# "pointer being freed was not allocated" error with core plot array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, malloc, core-plot

I'm drawing a waveform of the incoming audio in the microphone by using core plot.
It works great but i sometime get this error :
malloc: *** error for object 0x175a1550: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.
It happens occasionally (after 1 minute, 10 minutes, 1 hour...it depends!) when the core plot array is being cleared.

```
-(void)refreshScope: (NSTimer*)theTimer;
{
    if ([[audio dataForScope] count] == 500)
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadDataOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [[audio dataForScope] removeAllObjects]; // HERE !!!!
    }
}

-(void) reloadDataOnMainThread
{
    [audioScope reloadData];
}
```

The dataForScope array (mutable) is alloc/init in the audio class of my code. It is filled with integer of the audio buffer.
I have tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to work. I always get the same error
Any ideas ?
Thank you.

EDIT :

```
-(void)processAudio:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList{
    AudioBuffer sourceBuffer = bufferList->mBuffers[0];

    memcpy(tempBuffer.mData, bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData, bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);

    int16_t* samples = (int16_t*)(tempBuffer.mData);

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.mDataByteSize / 2; ++i )
        {
            if(i % 5 == 0)
            {
                if ([dataForScope count] == 500)
                {
                    scopeIndex = 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    float scopeTime = scopeIndex * 1000.0 / SampleRate;
                    id xScope = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: scopeTime];
                    id yScope = [NSNumber numberWithInt: samples[i]/100];
                    [dataForScope addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:xScope, @"xScope", yScope, @"yScope", nil]];
                }

                scopeIndex = scopeIndex + 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you are adding items to the dataforScope array.

Comment: Your NSMutableArray addObject code is fine, so that's not the issue. How are you allocating and freeing tempBuffer.mData

Comment: Why is samples declared as a pointer to an integer, but then you are using it as an array of integers? Does samples[i] return an integer or pointer?

Comment: Are `-refreshScope:` and `-processAudio:` always called from the same thread and/or GCD queue? If not, you have a locking issue with the `dataForScope` array.

Comment: @Joel, I am really new in iOS dev. Regarding the audio part of the code, I took the one from the Riograph [link](https://github.com/jar-son/rioGraph). Then I added core plot. Does it help you to better understand ? Thank you.

Comment: @Eric, you are right, processAudio does not run on the main thread. What could I try then ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `[[audio dataForScope] removeAllObjects];` executes before you call `-reloadData` on the plot. This ensures the `dataForScope` array is ready whenever the plot requests its new data.

The plot datasource methods are called on the main thread. If they read the `dataForScope` array directly, you need to make sure all accesses to that array (reads and writes) occurs on the main thread so there are no conflicts.

Comment: if I call removeAllObjects BEFORE -reloadData, then I'll have no data to plot ?! Maybe I didn't understand correctly...

Comment: `-reloadData` doesn't pull the new data until the next display update. Are you trying to load blocks of 500 points to the graph and then start collecting a new dataset? Don't clear the array until you know the datasource has all of the new data.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to refresh the graph every 500 points, so when dataForScope is full. I first tried to reloadData directly in the for condition (audio class), but the graph didn't refresh. I'm obviously not doing it correctly.

Comment: Call `-reloadDataOnMainThread` when the `dataForScope` array is full, but don't clear it until the plot has loaded all of the new data. If data continues coming in before it is all transferred to the plot, you may need a second data array and swap which one is gathering new data and which one supplies the plot.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks Eric. Is there any method to check if the plot has terminated to load all the 500 points ?

Comment: It depends on which datasource methods you are using. Some of them are called for each data index and others request a whole block of data at once. Just make sure all 500 points for each field (e.g., x and y for a scatter plot) have been requested.

Comment: Finally it works ! I created a second array and it is just perfect. Thank you very much Eric.